# Error sending media files in whatsapp chatbot with dialogflow and Twilio

Tags: twilio, dialogflow-es, chatbot, whatsapp

I'm trying to send some media files from dialogflow to Twilio Whatsapp chatbot, using the custom payloads, but always get me an Error - 11200.

I've checked the error but all looks correct

It's anyway to send it from dialogflow or I need to use another way to send media files?

Comment: Thanks for the response, but your example it's not using dialogflow and it's a must for me

Comment: You need to direct deal with custom payload you need to check whiile sending custom payload, make sure is twilio is expecting same or not

Comment: Can you share the code/custom payload that you are using?

Comment: I was using the wrong JSON code. I was talking with dialogflow support and said to me that I need to use an additional code for it. I don't know which is the best way to send audio/video/image message in dialogflow

Comment: I solved it using nodejs inside the fulfillment editor code.
Thanks for the support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many attempts and mails with dialogflow support and Twilio support, I have discovered that at this moment it's not possible to send media files from dialogflow to Twilio service directly. It's about what type of response send dialogflow and witch one are expected form Twilio. The better solution is to develop it with python.